# Get variable outside exception Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am calling an API with the urllib. When something is not as expected, the API throws an error at the user (E.G. `HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type`). But next to that, the API returns a JSON with more information. I would like to pass that json to the exception and parse it there, so I can give information to the user about the error.

Is that possible? And if, how is it done?

Extra info:

Error: HTTPError

--EDIT--

On request, here is some code (I want to read resp in the exception):

```
def _sendpost(url, data=None, filetype=None):
    try:
        global _auth
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
        req.add_header('User-Agent', _useragent)
        req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _auth['access_token'])
        if filetype is not None:
            req.add_header('Content-Type', filetype)
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req, data)
        data = json.loads(resp.read().decode('utf-8'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
    return data
```

--EDIT 2--
I do not want to use extra library's/modules. As I do not control the target machines.

Comment: Can you provide some code you have been playing around with?

Comment: @Jan Added the code to the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

try:
    request = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.gutefrage.net')
    response = urllib.urlopen(request)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    error_message = e.read()
    print(error_message)
```

## Output

```
b'{"error":{"message":"X-Api-Key header is missing or invalid","type":"API_REQUEST_FORBIDDEN"}}'
```

Not asked but with module json you could convert it to dict via

```
import json
json.loads(error_message.decode("utf-8"))
```

Which gives you the dict out of the byte string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with using urllib, then you can use the error to read the text of the response, and load that into JSON.

```
from urllib import request, error
import json

try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', _useragent)
    req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _auth['access_token'])
    if filetype is not None:
        req.add_header('Content-Type', filetype)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req, data)
    data = json.loads(resp.read().decode('utf-8'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
except error.HTTPError as e:
    json_response = json.loads(e.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

---

If you're not stuck to urllib, I would highly recommend you use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) module instead of `urllib`. With that, you can have something like this instead:

```
response = requests.get("http://www.example.com/api/action")
if response.status_code == 415:
    response_json = response.json()
```

requests doesn't throw an exception when it encounters a non-2xx series response code; instead it returns the response anyway with the status code added.

You can also add headers and parameters to these requests:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': _useragent,
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _auth['access_token']
}
response = requests.get("http://www.example.com/api/action", headers=headers)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, it is for a module for clients to use, we want as less as possible external modules.

Comment: @FalingDutchman It's possible to automate the installation of many modules during an installation process. In this case, there's one command to install it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode json.loads(e.read()) wont work because you must convert it to a string first with decode